# C# Behavior of ref readonly

Tags: c#, ref, c#-7.2

I was reading documentation on C# 7.2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/write-safe-efficient-code) and I came across this in regards to `ref readonly`:

> The compiler enforces that the caller can't modify the reference. Attempts to assign the value directly generate a compile-time error. However, the compiler can't know if any member method modifies the state of the struct. To ensure that the object isn't modified, the compiler creates a copy and calls member references using that copy. Any modifications are to that defensive copy.

This generated some confusion for me (and possibly some others), so I'd like to clarify the behavior now. Suppose I have a struct defined like this:

```
public struct Point3D
{
    private static Point3D origin = new Point3D(0,0,0);

    public static ref readonly Point3D Origin => ref origin;

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public int Z { get; set; }

    public static void ChangeOrigin(int x = 0, int y = 0, int z = 0)
    {
        origin = new Point3D(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

Now, suppose I used `ref readonly` to get `Point3D.Origin` and modified it:

```
ref readonly var origin = ref Point3D.Origin;
var originValue = Point3D.Origin;
Point3D.ChangeOrigin(1, 1, 1);

Console.WriteLine("Origin is: ({0}, {1}, {2})", origin.X, origin.Y, origin.Z);
Console.WriteLine("Origin is: ({0}, {1}, {2})", originValue.X, originValue.Y, originValue.Z);
```

The result from running this code is:

```
Origin is: (1, 1, 1)
Origin is: (0, 0, 0)
```

This is expected. The value in `origin` is updated when I call `ChangeOrigin` whereas the value in `originValue` is copied and therefore doesn't change. My question is in regards to the "defensive copy" mentioned above. Why is this necessary? The value in `origin` can't be changed without invoking compiler errors and the reference is updated properly when `Point3D.Origin` updates so what reason is there to have an extra copy of the object, which from what I gathered by reading the documentation, isn't updated?

Comment: You're asking us to tell you what the result of this code is? Can't you find that out by running the code? We're people, not computers.

Comment: @mason I'm asking partly because I was curious about the language feature and haven't upgraded to 7.2 yet and partially because I assumed someone would have more knowledge about it than I do. Also, because I thought it would be helpful for people who had questions about this in the future

Comment: @mason Yes, I could indeed run the code. But that wouldn't tell me _why_, the code behaves in a certain way, now would it. And that's the real impetus for this question. And, if you know why the code runs the way it does, then you wouldn't really need to run it.

Comment: @mason In short, I'm less curious about what the code does and more about why the code does behaves the way it does

Comment: Related github issue with SpinLock. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17310

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a value to a `readonly` field only in the following contexts:

- When the variable is initialized in the declaration.

  C# example:

  ```
   public readonly int y = 5;
  ```
- In an instance constructor of the class that contains the instance field declaration.
- In the static constructor of the class that contains the static field declaration.

These constructor contexts are also the only contexts in which it is valid to pass a `readonly` field as an `out` or `ref` parameter.

If you use a statement like the following example:

```
p2.y = 66; // Error
```

you will get the compiler error message:

> A readonly field cannot be assigned to (except in a constructor or a
> variable initializer)

The `readonly` modifier on a `ref` return indicates that the returned reference cannot be modified. The following example returns a reference to the origin. It uses the `readonly` modifier to indicate that callers cannot modify the origin:

```
private static readonly Point origin = new Point(0, 0);
public static ref readonly Point Origin => ref origin;
```

The type returned doesn't need to be a `readonly struct`. Any type that can be returned by `ref` can be returned by `ref readonly`.

This is all straight from the DOCs, and I hope it clarifies it for you! Happy coding!

So if you set `(1, 1, 1)` in the constructer, it will be `(1, 1, 1)` calling a change with a different method, as above, you get `(0, 0, 0)`

Comment: In that case, what do they mean by all this "defensive copy" business? Why create a copy of the object when an immutable reference is requested of it?

Comment: think of the copy like a shield, if you attempt to modify the base, it will mod the `defensive copy`, basically making your modification null, because when you use the reference it will grab the `hard copy` that is unaltered. you can keep changing the defensive copy but you will never get it from a call, and you cant alter the `base`

Comment: By the way, good catch on the compilation errors. I pulled my example directly from the Microsoft documentation, which doesn't compile >_<

Comment: they probably wrote them at the same time they wrote their windows 10 updates. ;)